# Convert a script address to Shelley address using Plutus

Tags: plutus, cardano-address, shelley

I have this script address of the type `Plutus.V1.Ledger.Address.Address`.

```
Address {addressCredential = ScriptCredential 31559888de4dd413f20557ff39f616eb3e8a52d36528f88e6aef2f8d,
 addressStakingCredential = Nothing}
```

Is there a way to convert this to a `ShelleyAddress` of the format `addr..` using `Plutus`?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer a while after posting this question. So, I am adding it here for reference. Using `toCardanoAddress` function from `module Ledger.Tx.CardanoAPI` conversion to `ShelleyAddress` can be done.

Example:

```
toCardanoAddress (Testnet $ NetworkMagic 1097911063) scriptAddress
```

You can unwrap the `Either` returned above if needed.